# An equation involving an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How do we find the function of radial distance $f(r)$ from an equation of the form $\int_a^b \nabla f(r)\cdot d\vec{r}=c$ for some constant $c$? 
$f(r)$ is radially symmetric.

Thank you.

Comment: Not enough information is given to uniquely specify the function. Also, $d\vec{r}$ indicates we are ranging over a several dimensions yet we integrate over just one.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Would the additional fact the $f(r)$ is radially symmetric help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your function's sole independent variable is r we have:

$\int_a^b \nabla f(r)\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_a^b \frac{df(r)}{dr} \hat{r} \cdot d\vec{r}=\int_a^bdf(r)=f(b)- f(a)=c $.

So your equation becomes:    $f(b)-f(a)=c \;   \  (1)$.

So your equation has infinite solutions because if you find a function $f$ that satisfies the condition (1) every function of the form $h=f+ct$ will satisfy it too.

Comment: THanks, chemeng, what is $t$ in $h=f+ct$?

Comment: No problem, *ct=constant number*. I didn't use the *c* symbol to avoid any confusion with the *c* used in your equation. If the answer is suitable for you mark the answer as acceptable:)